# Mac booting loop, I can't recovery or boot from USB

Tags: macos, imac

im having a big issue with my iMac mid 2011, last night the Imac just reboot itself and after that i can't use it.

There is a white screen (see picture), the logo and loading is always there, sometimes the loading dont get to the end and the Imac reboot itself, an eterna loop of reboot.

I tried all methods about how recovery with USB, from Internet, from the recovery partion and nothing works, in fact the OS doesn't load any visual window like OS X Utility.

The thing is that i don't know if this is a hardware problem like HD or if this is a software problem.

I have the MacOS Sierra

Any idea about it?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: On such little data it's impossible to be certain, but I have a machine that will do that every so often. [DiskWarrior](https://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) fixes it every time. You'd need to create a bootable USB of it on another Mac.

Comment: @Tetsujin i have a bootable USB and nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try to boot into **Verbose Mode**. This is a regular boot process, however, the graphical screen is turned off in favour of a terminal-like screen logging everything that happens during boot. This may give you the chance to see an error message indicating the cause of your problem. It is not too likely yet still possible so do give it a try.

To boot verbose you need to press `cmd-V` upon startup. You may release the keys just after the boot chime has passed. The screen should immediately switch to a white font on a black background. You need a fast eye to read these (cryptic!) messages as you cannot hold them.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, i did this before, but know i will try to check the errors.